# xls criado através de C#, porém não soma valores

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel

Possuo um método que gera excel(.xls), porém estou com um problem: o excel esta sendo gerado perfeitamente, mas quando tento somar os valores das células nada acontece, ele apenas soma se eu abrir célula por célula(não preciso mudar valor algum).

Na imagem abaixo tem um exemplo, todos os valores vem alinhado a esquerda mas quando clico na célula para editar eles automaticamente se alinham a direita e passa a ser possível fazer a soma dos mesmos.

[image: Os que possuem traço vermelho é possível somar]

Os que possuem traço vermelho é possível somar porque já cliquei na célula como se fosse editar seu valor. E os outros valores não são possíveis somar porque não cliquei para edita-los nenhuma vez.

O código que formato as células é este:

```
if (gradeColuna != null)
                    switch (gradeColuna.type)
                    {
                        case "string": excelRange.NumberFormat = "@"; break;
                        case "date": excelRange.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/aaaa"; break;
                        case "datetime": excelRange.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/aaaa hh:mm;@"; break;
                        case "double": excelRange.NumberFormat = "#.##0,00#"; break;
                    }
                else
                    excelRange.NumberFormat = "@";
```

E o que atribui os valores é este:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dados.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < dados.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                xlWorkSheet.Cells[linha, i] = dr[i].ToString()
                                                   .Replace("01/01/1900  00:00:00", "")
                                                   .Replace("00:00:00", "")
                                                   .Replace("01/01/1900", "")
                                                   .Trim()
                                                   .Replace("\\n", Environment.NewLine);

                if (dr[i].ToString().Contains("\\n"))
                    xlWorkSheet.Range[xlWorkSheet.Cells[linha, i], xlWorkSheet.Cells[linha, i]].WrapText = true;

                if (dr[i].ToString().Length >= 100)
                    xlWorkSheet.Columns[i].ColumnWidth = 100;

                decimal valorTemp = 0M;
                if (decimal.TryParse(dr[i].ToString(), out valorTemp))
                {
                    var teste = xlWorkSheet.Cells[linha, i];
                    if (dados.Columns[i].DataType.Name == "Decimal" || dados.Columns[i].DataType.Name == "Double")
                        xlWorkSheet.Cells[linha, i].Value = valorTemp.ToString("N2");
                }
            }

            linha++;
        }

        xlWorkSheet.Columns.AutoFit();
        xlWorkSheet.Rows.AutoFit();
```

Caso tenham alguma duvida ou algo mal explicado, me questionem por favor.

Observações:

1. Estou usando o Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel e alguns valores estão
   zerados mas isto não é a causa de não somar, já verifiquei isto.
2. Vale ressaltar que isso só ocorre com double.

Comment: Talvez o Excel não esteja reconhecendo esses valores inicialmente como numéricos e interpretando como texto. Onde está o resto relevante do código?

Comment: Tentou inverter os separadores? `"#,##0.00`